# How to compute the jacobian matrix of a tensor in tensorflow, where the size of the tensor is None

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None,3])
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones([3, 1]))
w = tf.matmul(x,v)
```

before `sess.run`, the size of `w` is unknown. 
How to compute the gradients of all the element in `w` with respect to `v` (computing the jacobian when building the graph)?

Comment: I removed my answer because the target value in `tf.gradients` is being summed and my answer didn't address that.